# how to rename the @Queryparam value(Fin) in springboot such that in JSON i can pass chassisNumber to instead Fin

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, postman

This is My Springboot Post call, need to rename the Fin attribute to chassisNumber.

```
AddAdditionalInformationResponseDto addAdditionalInformation(
            @QueryParam("fin") String fin,
            @ApiParam(value = "Date of first registration (Example:YYYY-MM-DD)", required = false, format = "date") @QueryParam("firstRegistrationDate") String firstRegistrationDate,
            @ApiParam(value = "license Plate(Example:1UPG459)", required = false) @QueryParam("licensePlate") String licensePlate,
            
            );
```

current Json:
{
"fin":"wer3rr",
"firstregistrationdate":02-09-2022,
"licenseplate":"ap092323"
}

Expected:

urrent Json:
{
"chassisNumber":"wer3rr",
"firstregistrationdate":02-09-2022,
"licenseplate":"ap092323"
}

I don't want to rename fin, but in json i should pass chassis instead fin.

Comment: Why dont you just change queryparam name and keep field name as Fin like -@QueryParam("chassisNumber") String fin

Comment: If i rename the @QueryParam , can i pass chassisNumber in Json?

Comment: why dont you give it a try.